# Javascript scope and hashmaps

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

I have a function that duplicates a map containing key:function pairs,
wrapping each function with a calling funcion.

```
function duplicateFunctionsMap(functionsMap){

    var newMap = {};

    for (var name in functionsMap){

        var originalFunc = functionsMap[name];

        newMap[name] = function(){
            originalFunc();
        }
    }

    return  newMap;
}
```

now trying to run any of the entries in the duplicated map turns out always calling the last one

```
duplicateFunctionsMap({
                      first: function(){alert("first");}, 
                       last: function(){alert("last");}
                      })["first"](); // outputs "last"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to introduce a scope to prevent `originalFunc` from changing. Functions introduce a new scope, but `for` loops do not:

```
for (var name in functionsMap){
    (function(originalFunc) {
        newMap[name] = function(){
            originalFunc();
        }; // <-- add semicolon at end of expression, too
    })(functionsMap[name]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nine million duplicates on this but here it goes.. javascript
doesn't have a block level scope. Repeat that.

So it becomes:

```
function duplicateFunctionsMap(functionsMap) {

    var newMap = {};

    for (var name in functionsMap) {
         var originalFunc = functionsMap[name];

        newMap[name] = (function (originalFunc) {
            return function () {
            originalFunc();
            };
        })(originalFunc);

    }

    return newMap;
}
```

Note that if you want to duplicate functions that use context, arguments and return values you need to do this:

```
newMap[name] = (function (originalFunc) {
    return function () {
        return originalFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(originalFunc);
```

Otherwise your duplicate function loses all that good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

inside your for cycle you've probably created a closure. try this code that creates an inner anonymous immediately executed function

```
for (var name in functionsMap){
    (function(_of) { 
        newMap[name] =  _of;
    }(functionsMap[name]))
}
```

See also [javascript closure immediate evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413916/javascript-closure-immediate-evaluation)

Comment: In this case the anonymous function is overkill, since setting directly works too.

Comment: this doesn't duplicate the functions

Answer (score 0):

The other answers on this page are correct. But for a detailed explanation on why see my answer to a previously related question:

[Please explain the use of JavaScript closures in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops/3572616#3572616)